# Pad strings in a column of a data.frame

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` `X`, with a column `A` filled with `chr`, most of them are of `nchar` = 5, but some are of `nchar`=4. I want to put a `0` in front of those.

I would do it with the following kind-of-pseudo-code :

```
foreach( element_of_X$A as a ){  # this line is pseudo-code for Idk how to do it in R
    if(nchar(a) < 5){            # I think these lines are valid
        paste0(0,a)              # I think these lines are valid
    }
}
```

(Obviously I come from PHP). How can I do that in clean R code ? (That, or a more efficient solution)

Thanks

Comment: see `?sprintf` for left padding string

Comment: That's a nice alternative to paste0(), but I'm not sure how it answers my problem...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `dplyr` and `stringr` you could do the following

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

## Assuming "element_of_X" has element 'A'
element_of_X <-
    element_of_X %>%
    mutate(A = str_pad(A, 5, side = 'left', pad = '0'))
```

**Edit**

Or perhaps more simply, as suggested in the comments:

```
element_of_X$A <- str_pad(element_of_X$A, 5, side = 'left', pad = '0')
```

Comment: I think you mean "%05s" not "%04s".  Also, `?sprintf` indicates that "this zero-pads on some platforms and is ignored on others," so not a universal solution

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 I fixed the typo.  I will update the post to use a cross platform solution.  Thanks for pointing both out.

Comment: Why not x$A=str_pad(x$A, 5, pad = "0")?

Comment: @Luke Yes, you can do as you suggested, and there is an answer with your suggested code; also, if I answered this today, I would likely do something like you are suggesting. It has been a while since I answered this but likely I was thinking two things, I often am doing thing in a bigger (dplyr) context, and one can adapt as needed.

Answer (score 6):

Actually `sprintf` didn't work for me, so if you don't mind a common dependency:

```
#reproducible example -- this happens with zip codes sometimes
X <- data.frame(A = c('10002','8540','BIRD'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# X$A <- sprintf('%05s',X$A) didn't work for me
# Note in ?sprintf: 0: For numbers, pad to the field width with leading zeros. 
# For characters, this zero-pads on some platforms and is ignored on others.

library('stringr')
X$A <- str_pad(X$A, width=5, side='left', pad='0')
X
#      A
#1 10002
#2 08540
#3 0BIRD
```

or, if you prefer a base solution, the following is equivalent:

```
X$A <- ifelse(nchar(X$A) < 5, paste(c(rep("0",5-nchar(X$A)), X$A), collapse=""), X$A)
```

(note this works on strings of length 4 or less, not just 4)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
X$A <- ifelse(nchar(X$A) < 5, paste("0", X$A, sep=""), X$A)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (assuming data frame name and column name are right):

```
element_of_X$a <- with(element_of_X , ifelse(nchar(a) == 4, paste('0', a, sep = ''), a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
x$A=str_pad(x$A, 5, pad = "0")
```